# What is the meaning of "Between Anne and Jack's house there is just one vacant house"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Between Anne and Jack's house there is just one vacant house.

Does it mean there is just one house between Anne and Jack's house and it is vacant, or 
does it mean that there may be more that one house between Anne and Jack's house but only one of these houses is vacant?

Comment: It could be either, and there's nothing to tell you which.

Comment: Either is suitable; more context is needed.

Comment: I feel it should be "Between Anne's and Jack's house...", so that it is clear that Anne's house and Jack's house are two different houses and there are several houses between these two and out of those only one is vacant.

Comment: Interestingly, writing this with comma:  *one, vacant house* would make it unambiguous: only one house, and it's vacant. The comma is optional though and only rephrasing this as *Between Anne and Jack's houses just one house is vacant* would make it unambiguous the other way.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: yes.

:)

Longer answer: the sentence is ambiguous, and both of the interpretations you list are equally valid. It's possible that context would help you choose a particular interpretation, but just based on grammar/semantics alone, there's no reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: "Yes" is not a valid answer to an "A or B" question:)

Comment: @NS.X.: sure it is. "Would you like something to eat or drink?" If you're both hungry and thirsty, but have no information about what sort of food and drink are available, the only possible answer is "Yes, please".

Comment: @NS.X.: Would you be happier with a *slightly* longer (by one letter) answer? **Both**, for example?